# How to auto generate a custom ID for each record in a MongoDb collection?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, mongoose

The MERN application that I'm trying to develop has a requirement that each record in the collection should have custom unique ID that should be auto generated each time when a new record is added.

Examples of the how required IDs shoudl look like:

IDs for employees would look like: EMP00001, EMP00002, EMP00003...

IDs for Branches would look like: BR00001, BR00002, BR00003... etc.

Please note that this should be auto saved with each record.

I didn't find any satisfactory help from MongoDB docs (https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/generating-globally-unique-identifiers-for-use-with-mongodb) where the available options to create custom identifiers doesn't fulfill my requirements.

I've also read that it is not ideal to create IDs other that MongoDb's own ObjectIds, but i don't understand how it would address the unique business requirements where records needs to have a simple understandable IDs not some random junk of digits.

I would appreciate if you could help with any official solution or if there's a work around that could help in achieving the above mentioned requirement.

Answer (score 0):

It is highly recommended not to edit the **_id** of your document, one way to solve it is to create a field for *custom_id* that generates a unique ID by combining *Collection_type* (for example an employee table can have the type EMP) concatenated with the total number of documents in the target collection..

For example:
If you want to add a new branch, and you have the number of current branches (96 let's say), then you can concatenate the *Collection_type* with the *number_of_current_branches* to become BR00096.

Comment: I don't see any problem in creating another custom_id field if it solved the issue. But would the solution you mentioned would not create problem when the records will be deleted because the next custom_id would be based on the number of records.

Comment: Usually, when records are deleted they should be saved but as deactivated account, no record must be deleted for analytical purposes or rehiring, etc... 
Anyway I already mentioned it is a one way to solve that problem, and i hope it at least give you a hint if that's not the answer ur expecting

Answer (score 0):

As you asked to generate a costume _id then follow the following way.

```
 const ObjectId = require('mongoose').Types.ObjectId; // use you logic to generate the _id

    YourMode.insert({_id: ObjectId , name: "abc"})
   .then(data=> console.log("inserted")
   .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

Comment: How would this be auto incremented? I don't necessarily want to replace the default ObjectId. It Should be purely custom and should auto increment just like we would easily do in an sql database.

Comment: If you need to increment automatically then you need to fetch the count if total data and add one to that like below
let count = await YourMode.count();

Comment: If you need to increment automatically then you need to fetch the count if total data and add one to that like below
let count = await YourMode.count();
eId = `EMP0000${count}`

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to use custom function to generate custom employee or branch IDs.
We'll simply **generate employee ID using total count of documents in collection** you want to save your data.
So we **don't need to download any external NPM module** for generating IDs.

```
// create const 'emp' with existing Schema 'Employee'...
const emp = new Employee(req.body)

// get total employees saved to database...
const totalNumberOfEmpInDb = await Employee.countDocuments()
// convert number to string, so we can concatenate 0s easily...
let numberToString = totalNumberOfEmpInDb.toString()

// If length of number string is less than 5 then add leading 0s in nuberToString
if(numberToString.length < 5){
    for (let i = numberToString.length; i < 5; i++){
        numberToString = '0' + numberToString
    }
}
emp.empID = `EMP${numberToString}`

// save emp data to database
emp.save()


// Suppose total employees saved to databases are 55
// So in string format, '55' contain only 2 characters, which means it is less than 5 characters
// So in for loop, leading 3 zeros will be added to string '55'
// new string will be '00055'
// we will append this string '00055' with 'EMP' and save in empID variable
// So new empID will be 'EMP00055'
```

**Remember, we are not tampering with _id which generates in mongo automatically. New empID parameter is being saved to database.**